# Map with key as string and value as a list of key value pairs in C++

Tags: c++

I want to map phone number (string) of students to their corresponding marks and rank.  Format will look like:

```
myMap["9876543210"] = {"Marks" => 90, "Rank" => 3}
```

How can this be done in C++ ?

Comment: Yes it can be done. Have you googled a possible answer first (c++ map might be a good start)

Comment: Your question has the word "map", and you didn't find or research the C++`std::map` class?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <map>

struct StudentData {
    int marks;
    int rank;
};

typedef std::map<std::string, StudentData> studentDataRepository;
```

Comment: Perhaps a little explanation in answers in the future

Comment: Ok :-) I'm learning...